# How to use `nx affected` with auto-generated source?

Tags: monorepo

In my nx mono-repo there's a lib called `data-access`. This lib has a `schema.graphql` which I use to auto-generate typescript types/interfaces and some React hooks (using `codegen`).
The `schema.graphql` is under version control but the files generated are not.

There are other libraries in the repo that depends on the `data-access`.

I'd like to setup CI in such way that:

- If there are changes in the `schema.graphql` the auto-generated files should be re-generated.
- the libs/apps that depends on `data-access` should be built again

But if there's no change in the schema, no need to regenerate.

The problem I'm facing is: who does it works when there's no change in the schema?
If the files are generated and not under version control, does it means the dependants will fail because the auto-generated files are missing?
And if I auto-generate them every time, even if there's no change in the schema, does it means it will trigger the `affected` in all dependants ?

Note: can we have `nx` as a new tag?